# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, programación-móvil, nullpointerexception

Me arroja el error en la siguiente línea de código

Estoy tratando de hacer las notificaciones de un chat y arroja el error anteriormente dicho, si alguien sabe lo que puedo hacer o alguien tiene un código relacionado, lo agradecería

```
reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
                username.setText(user.getUsername());
                        if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {
                            profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                        } else {
                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


---

Muy bien amigo, me soluciono el error. pero al momento de implementarlo y sarle run me lanzo este otro: ¿me podria ayudar?
```

private void readUsers() {

```
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (search_users.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                mUsers.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                    assert user != null;
                    assert firebaseUser != null;
                    if (!user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                        mUsers.add(user);
                    }
                }
            }

                userAdapter = new UserAdapter(getContext(), mUsers, false);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
            }
```

Comment: Que otro error obtienes ? solo indicas que es en otro mètodo, por favor no olvides revisa [ask],saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es debido a que al obtener el objeto User, este no contiene valor en la propiedad ImageURL, en este caso lo recomendable es validar primeramente si este valor no es null.

Pero ademàs es importante validar no tratar de cargar la image mediante Glide si la url tiene valor null ya que obtendràs otro error.

```
    if (user.getImageURL() != null && user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {
        profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    } else if (user.getImageURL() !=null) {
       Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
    }
```

Comment: Muy bien, allá debajo te deje otro comentario de lo que me sucedio

Answer (score 0):

En la línea que dice:

```
if (user.getImageURL().equals("default")) {
```

Invierte los operadores. Debe quedar así:

```
if ("default".equals(user.getImageURL())) {
```

Así, evitarás que se genere la excepción de puntero nulo.

Lo mismo sugiero que hagas en esta línea de código:

```
if (search_users.getText().toString().equals("")) {
```

Invirtiendo los operadores, debe quedar así:

```
if ("".equals(search_users.getText().toString())) {
```